# Unable to import process configuration in TFS 2018 TF400522 error “invalid work item category”

Tags: tfs

Unable to import process configuration file due to TF400522 error “invalid work item category”

*The following element contains an error: PortfolioBacklog(Zions.InitiativeCatego
ry). TF400522: The following value is not a valid work item category: Zions.Init
iativeCategory. You must specify a valid category.*

created a new work item type called “Initiative”
Imported the WIT successfully via VSTS TFS plugin
Work item appears on the web ui
Edited the Agile Template‘category.xml’ to include the new Initiative work item category

```
<CATEGORY name="Initiative Category" refname="Microsoft.InitiativeCategory"><DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="Initiative" /></CATEGORY>
```

Then I added the initiative category to the processconfiguration.xml file

```
<PortfolioBacklogs><PortfolioBacklog category="Microsoft.InitiativeCategory" pluralName="Initiatives" singularName="Initiative" workItemCountLimit="1000"><States><State value="New" type="Proposed" /><State value="Active" type="InProgress" /><State value="Resolved" type="InProgress" /><State value="Closed" type="Complete" /></States><Columns><Column refname="System.WorkItemType" width="100" /><Column refname="System.Title" width="400" /><Column refname="System.State" width="100" /><Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" width="50" /><Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue" width="50" /><Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea" width="100" /><Column refname="System.Tags" width="200" /></Columns><AddPanel><Fields><Field refname="System.Title" /></Fields></AddPanel></PortfolioBacklog>
```

Initiative should be a parent of ‘Epic’ so I added that to the Epic entry in processonfig.xml

```
<PortfolioBacklog category="Microsoft.EpicCategory" pluralName="Epics" singularName="Epic" parent="Microsoft.InitiativeCategory" workItemCountLimit="1000"><States><State value="New" type="Proposed" /><State value="Active" type="InProgress" /><State value="Resolved" type="InProgress" /><State value="Closed" type="Complete" /></States><Columns><Column refname="System.WorkItemType" width="100" /><Column refname="System.Title" width="400" /><Column refname="System.State" width="100" /><Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.Effort" width="50" /><Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BusinessValue" width="50" /><Column refname="Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ValueArea" width="100" /><Column refname="System.Tags" width="200" /></Columns><AddPanel><Fields><Field refname="System.Title" /></Fields></AddPanel></PortfolioBacklog>
```

using witadmin i ran the import process config command,

*C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtens
ions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer>
witadmin.exe importprocessconfig /collection:https://tfs.testqa.zionsbank.com/InfoSec /p:"Template Test" /f:"C:\Users\z070187\Documents\TFSAgileTemplateCustom2\Agile\WorkItem Tracking\Process\ProcessConfiguration.xml"*

Get the error,

*The following element contains an error: PortfolioBacklog(Zions.InitiativeCatego
ry). TF400522: The following value is not a valid work item category: Zions.InitiativeCategory. You must specify a valid category.*

If I remove the category entries for ‘initiative’I can import successfully

From what I understand this category syntax should work fine.The category format from what I understand should meet formatting requirements. Any ideas would be helpful

```
<CATEGORIES> <CATEGORY name="category display name" refname="category reference name"> <DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE name="work item type reference name" /> <WORKITEMTYPE name="work item type reference name" /> </CATEGORY> </CATEGORIES>
```

Comment: Just check if there is a category called `Zions.InitiativeCategory`, I guess the category was not defined correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I tested on my side and everything works as expected.

1. Export a WIT definition and modify it to be a new WIT called
   `Initiative`:
   [image]
2. Import the new WIT with `Process Editor` or `witadmin`
3. Export `category.xml` and add a new category, then import the
   `category.xml` file

   `<CATEGORY name="Initiative Category"
   refname="Microsoft.InitiativeCategory"><DEFAULTWORKITEMTYPE
   name="Initiative" /></CATEGORY>`
   [image]
4. Export `processconfiguration.xml` file with `witadmin`, edit the
   file to [Configure a backlog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/customize/reference/process-configuration-xml-element?view=vsts#configure-a-backlog) and set `Initiative` as the parent
   of ‘`Epic`’:

[image]
 5. Import the `processconfiguration.xml` file with `witadmin`

```
witadmin importprocessconfig /collection:http://server:8080/tfs/defaultcollection /p:TFVC-Agile /f:C:\temp\ProcConf.xml
```

6. Check the results:

[image]