# On VSTS Can I Customise the Relationship Between Work Item Parents and Children

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I would like to know if anyone has successfully defined default child relationships for Work Item Types in VSTS?

I have the following structure:

- Themes
- Initiatives
- Epics
- Features
- Stories

Instead of Initiatives creating Epics, I would like for children of Initiatives to be defaulted to Stories instead of Epics.

Is that kind of customisation possible within VSTS? If so, how?

I've been trawling the documentation and have not yet found a way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot do that within VSTS, no such a built-in feature for now.

We can only do that in **on-premise TFS** by exporting the `processconfiguration.xml` file and custom it accordingly.

Refer to my answer in another thread : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49998429/7466674

Comment: @Moby's Stunt Double Is that answered your question? any update?

Comment: It does and thanks for the link to you provided to a comprehensive answer of yours.

Answer (score 1):

No, we  can not do that. VSTS backlog supports strong hierarchy for parent and child. But if you add child user story directly to work item from another parent level you may see this link and backlog item on backlog:

1. Add link

[image]

2. View on backlog

[image]

Comment: That is the exact workaround we've been using. Thank you very much, Shamrai for taking the time to detail it out. I'm sure it will help others with similar questions.